# Relatively Position Raphael Objects

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, raphael

I've been messing around with Raphael.js recently and I've run into a problem regarding the position of each Raphael object.

I want to create an arbitrary amount of 'canvases' but have them arranged within a div, already positioned on the page. I've been trying to figure out a way to get them to behave something like a block element, but haven't come up with an answer. Each new raphael object is placed outside of any div.

Here's the html:

```
...
#content{height:100%; width:980px; margin:0 auto;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
...
```

and the javascript:

```
var previews = [];
var prevSize = 25;
var spacing = 10;

//get container
var container =  document.getElementById('content');

//get container width
var containerWidth = parseInt(getComputedStyle(container,"").getPropertyValue('width'));

var prevsPerRow =containerWidth/(prevSize+spacing);
var rowsPerPage = 20;

for(var y=0; y<rowsPerPage-1; y++){
    for(var x=0; x<prevsPerRow; x++){
        var preview = Raphael((x*prevSize)+(x*spacing), (y*prevSize)+(y*spacing),prevSize, prevSize);
        previews.push(preview);
    }
}

for(var x=0; x<previews.length-1; x++){
    var temp = previews[x];
    var rectangle =temp.rect(0,0,prevSize,prevSize);
    rectangle.attr('fill','black');
}
```

One solution I was considering was simply adding the offset of the desired div to the x and y coords of the object, but this doesn't seem like the best solution.

Thanks for the help!

edit: Here is a jsfiddle to help elucidate exactly what I'm getting at.
http://jsfiddle.net/xpNBr/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, this is two years too late but I'm not seeing an answer here.  So for posterity and future seekers: I'd use the element or element Id factory methods supplied by raphael as described [here](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Raphael).

From that page:

```
// Each of the following examples create a canvas
// that is 320px wide by 200px high.
// Canvas is created at the viewport’s 10,50 coordinate.
var paper = Raphael(10, 50, 320, 200);
// Canvas is created at the top left corner of the #notepad element
// (or its top right corner in dir="rtl" elements)
var paper = Raphael(document.getElementById("notepad"), 320, 200);
// Same as above
var paper = Raphael("notepad", 320, 200);
// Image dump
var set = Raphael(["notepad", 320, 200, {
    type: "rect",
    x: 10,
    y: 10,
    width: 25,
    height: 25,
    stroke: "#f00"
}, {
    type: "text",
    x: 30,
    y: 40,
    text: "Dump"
}]);
```

Comment: Better late than never! I haven't touched Raphael since asking this heh, but I'm sure it will be of help for someone. Thanks!

Comment: Running it in a jsfiddle shows that text object is not relative to rect object in terms of it's coordinates. Both of them are relative to canvas. How i can draw one rectangle with coordinates relative to a parent rectangle. Both in a same canvas ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a different container for every newly created *canvas*.
Here is a working example, using the *addCanvas* function to create every new element:

http://jsfiddle.net/creaweb/KtNPS/5/

Note that the spacing between canvas blocks is defined in CSS, as well as their size.